# не получается вывести только четные элементы в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы

Только начинаю изучать javascript, столкнулся с проблемой, при выводе только чётных цифр элементов массива, при условии что и позиция элемента тоже четная. Вот код:

```js
var numbers = new Array(20, 15, 6, 32, 18, 0, -5, 4, 11);

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  var number = numbers[i];

  if (number & 1 && i & 1) {
    console.log("Число " + number + " на позиции " + i + " нечётное");
  } else {
    console.log("Число " + number + " на позиции " + i + " чётное");
  }
}
```

Но у меня выводятся все элементы. Нужно именно чётные по факту и по позиции... А они выводятся и нечетные и четные (все). Что я делаю не так? Пробовал убирать `else`, но он всё равно выводит не то, что нужно, например ***Число 4 на позиции 7 чётное*** - это не должно выводиться, т.к. позиция 7 - нечётная.

Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменяйте условие на такое:
`if (!(number & 1) && !(i & 1)) {`

```js
var numbers = new Array(20, 15, 6, 32, 18, 0, -5, 4, 11);

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  var number = numbers[i];

  if (!(number & 1) && !(i & 1)) {
    console.log("Число " + number + " на позиции " + i + " чётное");
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! Так заработало. А не подскажете что значит "!" перед скобками?

Comment: @ЕвгенийРоднов это оператор [НЕ](https://learn.javascript.ru/logical-ops#ne). Он преобразует значение на противоположное.

Comment: Всё равно не очень понимаю, Это же получается, что если условие не верное, то он должен переходить в else, где у меня был вывод... Почему он тогда выводил все чётные, но с нечётной позицией?

Comment: Даже если я подставлю также скобки if ((number & 1) && (i & 1)) {, то он всё равно выводит неправильно в else

Comment: @ЕвгенийРоднов ну смотрите, у Вас дословно было "если число нечетное И позиция нечетная, то..." т.е. все остальные варианты выполнятся в else. Например "Число 4 на позиции 7 чётное" - не попадёт в if, поэтому и выведится в else.

Comment: Кажется начинаю понимать... Но пока сложно въехать до конца. Спасибо большое за помощь!!